# Diagnosing "contains undefined reference for architecture" at linking phase

Tags: c++, macos, qt, linker, ld

I'm trying to build a x86_64 application on MacOSX, using qmake/qt. I was able to compile in QT4, but not in QT5.

Anyway, after running qmake to generate my makefiles etc:

qmake -recursive -spec macx-clang  app.pro CONFIG+='release static'

Then when I run make, eventually I end up here:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 -Wl,-dead_strip -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -o (...author's note--tons of .o files here...)  -L../lib -L../../debug -F/Users/seth/workspace/qt5.1.0//5.1.0/clang_64/lib -lprotobuf -framework Security -framework SecurityInterface -framework ApplicationServices -framework CoreFoundation -lxml2 -lbz2 -lxar -framework ScriptingBridge  -L/Users/seth/workspace/qt5.1.0//5.1.0/clang_64/plugins/iconengines -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lFLAC  -framework Carbon -framework QtWebKitWidgets -framework QtQuick -framework QtQml -framework QtNetwork -framework QtCore -framework QtGui -framework QtOpenGL -framework QtWidgets -framework QtPrintSupport -framework Cocoa -framework QtWebKit -framework QtSql -framework QtSensors -framework QtSvg -framework QtXml -framework OpenGL -framework AGL`

`ld: '__ZN3Log16DebugE7QStringS3_' in debug/Log.o contains undefined reference for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I do not understand what 'undefined reference for architecture x86_64' means, and that's certainly the heart of the problem. Upon reading some other threads, some suggest that the libraries I'm linking against aren't x86_64, but after checking and rechecking, I can't find any non-x86_64 libraries involved in the process.

All my .o files from the build are `Mach-O 64-bit object x86_64`, after checking with the `file` command.

And for all libraries that I'm trying to reference (like libcrypto, for instance):

`Non-fat file: ../lib/libcrypto.a is architecture: x86_64`

And of course all the mac framework libraries are both 32/64bit capable.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could debug this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been fiddling all day, found it.

The method that the link is complaining about has this in it:

`qt_mac_execute_apple_script`

This method does not exist in qt5.

Also, earlier in the problematic file, I have this:

`extern bool qt_mac_execute_apple_script(const QString &script, AEDesc *ret);`

if i comment these lines, the error goes away.

So basically, a very bad compiler error for a missing symbol – because the compiler wasn’t nice enough to point out what the actual problem is beyond the vague architecture statement; probably made worse because I’m building my application statically coupled with the extern.